# Creating a Multi Authorisation Process from scratch

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have never used SP Designer 2013 before but have to create the following workflow:

1) Users put a request in to say they want authorisation and why they want it to download files

2) The Request is then reviewed by an IT Team/Person who can see what the user has access to and their information

3) The IT team then send this form to a managing director who will say Yes or No

4) Form then goes back to IT Team who give the authorisation or not

5) Form sent back to the User - Authorisation turned on/off and user notified

So it looks like I need an Input form, a database to store user info and this 5 step Workflow

Please could anyone help with resources/guides or if this is the best simple yet efficient approach to this task? I am looking at guides etc in the meantime

I would appreciate any replies.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've created a similar form that has 8 different departments authorising parts of the form.

This solution uses SharePoint 2013, InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2013 - note, I created my workflow using the SharePoint 2010 platform.

I did this with a custom list, a modified custom form (using InfoPath) and a different view for each section's approval.

The workflow is simple - it's a multi-faceted else - if branch and the workflow is initiated on item change.

It's not complicated, but it is involved. Form has multiple views and they are switched on form load depending on conditions. Eg. If [ITFirstCheck] is not blank, and [ManagingDirectorCheck] is blank > switch to "Managing Director" view. So on.

The workflow works in the same way.. IF [ITFirstCheck] is blank > Send an Email to IT team. Else IF [ITFirstCheck] is not blank and [ManagingDirectorCheck] is blank > Send Email to Managing Director. So on.

Here are some links to get you started on creating views, Customising a list form, and workflows.

**Customise your list form:** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-c1f9283d-f704-4bbe-a8aa-827425ab31ae

**Using Views:** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2

**Workflows:** https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b

Hope that gets you started!